# Understanding Memory.dmp file drive failure

Tags: windows-7, drivers, debug, minidumps, windbg

I have a desktop Windows 7 PC that keeps randomly rebooting, so I looked in the event log an there was lot of `Critical kernel-power` events followed by a `bugcheck` events.

[image: Event error in event viewer]

The `bugcheck` event pointed me to `C:\windows\MEMORY.dmp` file. Opening this in `WinDbg` and running the command `!analyze -v` on the file gave me the following output:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffffffffd8, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80002c6d25b, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS:  ffffffffffffffd8 

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!ExpScanGeneralLookasideList+a0
fffff800`02c6d25b 418b40d8        mov     eax,dword ptr [r8-28h]

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  System

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff880035169b0 -- (.trap 0xfffff880035169b0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=00000000000014ca rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80002c6d25b rsp=fffff88003516b40 rbp=0000000000000001
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000004 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po cy
nt!ExpScanGeneralLookasideList+0xa0:
fffff800`02c6d25b 418b40d8        mov     eax,dword ptr [r8-28h] ds:ffffffff`ffffffd8=????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002c78169 to fffff80002c78bc0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`03516868 fffff800`02c78169 : 00000000`0000000a ffffffff`ffffffd8 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`03516870 fffff800`02c76de0 : fffff880`00000000 fffff800`02c7d2e0 00000000`00000000 fffff800`02e1e440 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff880`035169b0 fffff800`02c6d25b : 00000000`00000000 fffff800`02eb0c40 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000003 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
fffff880`03516b40 fffff800`02c62a60 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000001 fffff800`02eb0c40 : nt!ExpScanGeneralLookasideList+0xa0
fffff880`03516ba0 fffff800`02c62fae : 00000000`00000008 fffff880`03516c10 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`00000000 : nt!ExAdjustLookasideDepth+0x40
fffff880`03516bd0 fffff800`02f1473a : fffffa80`03579530 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`0355b890 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBalanceSetManager+0x1be
fffff880`03516d40 fffff800`02c698e6 : fffff880`03100180 fffffa80`03579530 fffff880`0310afc0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`03516d80 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`03517000 fffff880`03511000 fffff880`03516700 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!ExpScanGeneralLookasideList+a0
fffff800`02c6d25b 418b40d8        mov     eax,dword ptr [r8-28h]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!ExpScanGeneralLookasideList+a0

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  531590fb

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.18409

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_nt!ExpScanGeneralLookasideList+a0

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_nt!ExpScanGeneralLookasideList+a0

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xa_nt!expscangenerallookasidelist+a0

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {2d4aa3ce-d2f6-a1c2-6e10-dc77b60dfba4}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

As you can see there is a fault with one of my drivers (`DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT`), but it doesn't tell me which one?

How do I go about finding the faulty driver?

**Update**

After another blue screen and reboot no `Bugcheck` event was logged but an event ID:`219 (212)` was logged, This reads:

```
The driver \Driver\WUDFRd failed to load for the device WpdBusEnumRoot\UMB\2&37c186b&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??
_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_GENERIC-&PROD_COMPACT_FLASH&REV_1.01#058F63626420&1#.
```

Comment: The bugcheck you have highlighted in the event log, does not appear to be the one you have analyzed (0x18 = REFERENCE_BY_POINTER). If your computer reboots with various bugcheck codes, note which you are experiencing. Try and collect multiple memory.dmp files. Alternatively, ensure kernel mem. dump is enabled, though they may not contain all needed info. As for the "Kernel-Power" event, see if http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=41&source=Kernel-Power helps

Comment: @abstrask Thanks for the response, I have update the image to the correct event shown in event viewer.

Comment: Thanks, though that does not provide any additional info. It would be more interesting with WinDbg analysis of the other bugchecks you experience :)

Comment: @abstrask Updated. :)

Comment: First step run several runs of memtestx86 without any errors then boot into safe mode to determine if the problem still happens when you don't load the AMD display drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound memtestx86 has been run a couple of times with no sign of errors.

Comment: The failure bucket ID/faulting symbol (nt!ExpScanGeneralLookasideList+a0) suggests to me a removable storage issue (that's where I [usually encounter them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), although sometimes this can happen with pool corruption from another driver. Your later event log entry (WpdBusEnumRoot) suggests some Western Digital storage, which may have buggy firmware, or might be failing. Identify what this device is, and back it up elsewhere. If this disk is not critical, remove it and see if stability improves.

Comment: If all else fails, I would try using gflags to enable page heap verification *(assuming this is pool corruption)*. The current exception is after the facts. The real culprit could be any other driver.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will post back with my findings.

Comment: No conclusion to this question? Having the same issue.